# Nuxt: All pages show a warning "Cannot stringify a function Object", how do I find out where it is coming from?

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a fairly large project everything works without any issues except for a warning. The warning shows "Cannot stringify a function Object" without any fnction name. So I am unable to figure out where it is coming from or what is causing it.

I tried commenting out all the middlewares I have, plugins I have and even created a new page with base minimum skeleton code and yet this warning appears when I access it.

What I am looking for is a way to find out the place or code where the warning is coming from?

Sorry, I can't share my code. Its the whole project and I am not able to recreate the warning as well. So is it possible to figure it out?

Comment: its something that is share data from server to client. So look at your data of components, asyncData, and store state. Somewhere in it you will have function instead of object or value.

Comment: @Aldarund thanks a lot. If you put this as an answer, I will mark it as solved. This was all I needed to figure out what was causing it. I was setting a state as an Object like `profileDetails: Object` as the default state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That warning comes from [@nuxt/devalue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxt/devalue) library, that is used by Nuxt to serialize  state from server to client. E.g. its used to pass state from asyncData, data, vuex store state from server to client, so you need to check it.

Comment: what is this for a weird answer and why is it accepted? What needs to be checked?

Comment: @Denzorrr what weird? pretty clear. state should be plain objects. that's it

Comment: that explained is much better :)

Answer (score 5):

To clarify, Nuxt serializes state from server to client i.e. it passes state from asyncData, data, vuex store state from server to client. The package that throws this error is @nuxt/devalue used by Nuxt.

To resolve, make sure that state is plain object.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help anyone, but the issue in my case was, my state Object was not normalized.

```js
export const state = () => ({
teacher: Object, // This was causing the warning
price: "",
})
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). This is for `JSON.stringify`.

> undefined, Functions, and Symbols are not valid JSON values. If any such values are encountered during conversion they are either omitted (when found in an object) or changed to null (when found in an array). JSON.stringify() can return undefined when passing in "pure" values like JSON.stringify(function() {}) or JSON.stringify(undefined).

`@nuxt/devalue` can handle the values below unlike `JSON.stringify`, But apparently still unable to handle functions or classes which in my case was the problem.

[Read more about `@nuxt/devalue`](https://github.com/nuxt-contrib/devalue#readme)

```js
cyclical references (obj.self = obj)
repeated references ([value, value])
undefined, Infinity, NaN, -0
regular expressions
dates
Map and Set
```

Just remove any function or type classes like `Object` or `String` and you should be good to go.

Hope this helped you.